How to start server in azure pipelines (Linux agent)?
My problem is specifically that I cannot reliably start a mock server in a step and keep it alive for the following steps. Either the server shuts down or the step never completes.
Context: for a couple of days I have been struggling with running a mock server on Azure pipelines. In this case I am using prism mock server, but the same issue applies to any other mock server (e.g. mockoon) I have developed a simple powershell script which reads contents of CSV file, which contains Port and Path columns. Then I create a number of prism mock servers for later use. Here's the key part of the script

foreach($pathAndPortPair in $pathsPortsDictionary.GetEnumerator()) {

  $key = $pathAndPortPair.Name
  $value = $pathAndPortPair.Value
  if (-Not $value.Contains($rootFolder)) {
    $value = Join-Path $rootFolder $value
  }

  if($IsWindows) {
    start-process pwsh.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit -command prism mock -d -p $key $value"
  }
  
  if($IsLinux) {
    ...
  }
}

where $key is port and $value is path to api spec.
It all works peachy on my Windows machine. But when I try to run the script on Azure pipeline I encounter a number of issues. Specifically, as I wrote above, I cannot reliably start the server and keep it alive for the following steps.
I tried the following commands to start the server:

Start-Process -FilePath "npx" -ArgumentList "prism mock -d -p $key $value - doesn't work, npm error is displayed.

Invoke-Expression "/bin/bash prism mock -d -p $key $value - doesn't work, bash scripting error:
/usr/local/bin/npx: npx: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token (' /usr/local/bin/npx: npx: line 3: const cli = require('../lib/cli.js')

Start-Job -ScriptBlock { prism mock -d -p $key $value } - the Jobs start... but then shut down, presumable just after the server starts. When I run Get-Job command, the Job status is marked as Complete, and no further operations on that server yield and desired results.

Start-Process -FilePath "prism" -ArgumentList "mock -d -p $key $value - this actually starts servers, but because the process runs in foreground, the step never ends in azure pipeline. I also get an error message: "The STDIO streams did not close within 10 seconds of the exit event from process '/usr/bin/pwsh'. This may indicate a child process inherited the STDIO streams and has not yet exited."

start-process pwsh.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit -command prism mock -d -p $key $value" - message is displayed: An error occurred trying to start process 'pwsh.exe' with working  | directory '/home/vsts/work/1/s'. No such file or directory


Does anyone have any other ideas? I am completely at a loss. How to run those servers in the background so that the pipeline steps ends, and a new step starts, but the servers are not terminated?

The first command is failing because the npx does not exist so you may be in the wrong folder.  Try the full path of npx.  The 2nd command is failing because bash shell is not recognizing the power shell script.  My best recommendation is to stay with one command and solve each issue one at a time.  You are going in five different paths and getting 5 different errors.

Thanks for the advice, but I gave up on using powershell. The paths were correct, I debugged them with echos within the pipelines. Anyway I did what I wanted to do with a bash script, attached in the post below.

I must admit I gave up on powershell and created a simple bash script that does the job. The key thing was using nohup prefix to prevent the process from being terminated once the step on Azure pipeline was complete. I also redirected outputs into null and set the process into background.
If there is a similar way to do this in powershell, I have no idea how to do it.
Anyway, I will share it here so that other people may benefit:
#!/bin/bash
# Get root folder of git repo
rootFolder=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

# Set path to csv file and read it
echo "Top-level directory: $rootFolder"
fullPath="$rootFolder/testFiles/csvs/test_csv.csv"
csv_file=$(cat $fullPath)

# Initialize an empty associative array (dictionary)
declare -A port_path_dict

# Split the CSV file into lines
lines=($csv_file)

# Skip the header line
for ((i=1; i<${#lines[@]}; i++)); do
    # Split each line into port and path
    line="${lines[$i]}"
    IFS=',' read -r port path <<< "$line"
    # Remove quotes from port and path
    port="${port//\"}"
    path="${path//\"}"
    # Add to the dictionary
    port_path_dict["$port"]="$path"
done

# Iterate over values in the dictionary and start servers
for port in "${!port_path_dict[@]}"; do
    path=${port_path_dict[$port]}
    # Run mock server but disable terminating it after terminal is closed
    nohup $(npx prism mock -d -p $port ${port_path_dict[$port]}) >/dev/null 2>&1 &
done

